# Need to under the Flutter thread

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The main thread running the Flutter app's Dart code is not the same main thread executing platform-specific code on the Android side. They are separate threads, and Flutter's architecture handles the coordination between them.

Is this a true statement?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true.
Flutter's architecture doesn't involve separate threads for executing Dart code and platform-specific code.

Flutter is designed to provide a single-threaded, event-driven architecture where the Dart code is responsible for managing both the UI logic and the business logic. This single-threaded model is referred to as the "UI thread" or "main thread" in the context of Flutter.

When you build a Flutter app, the Dart code is responsible for creating the UI hierarchy and handling user interactions. Additionally, Flutter's rendering engine is responsible for efficiently rendering the UI on the screen. This architecture provides a consistent and smooth UI experience across different platforms.

Comment: Isn't it used in flutter under the hood? Looking at output of `pgrep -aw flutterapp` on linux one can definitely see a lot of internal threads for a flutter app even without using isolates